# Issue with StreamDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, streams

I'm plotting a complicated vector field that is yielding the following particular StreamDensityPlot. I'm using the following command to plot it:

```
StreamDensityPlot[{Re[hfieldzr[m, ko, ki, r, 0, z][[1]]], 
Re[hfieldzr[m, ko, ki, r, 0, z][[2]]]}, {r, -R1, 1 R1}, {z, -d, d}, 
StreamStyle -> Black, ColorFunction -> ColorData["GreenPinkTones"], 
PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Above], 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 3, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
FontSize -> 20}], FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, ImageSize -> 500, 
AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

I'm basically getting this strange vector fields. Do you guys know how to fix that? Just want to emphasize this is not a pathology of my field, as when I use VectorDensityPlot I do not obtain this weirdness (See image bellow).

[image]

Here is the field in x and y direction, respectively:

```
{Re[(0.319694 - 2.45973*10^-17 I) (BesselJ[9, 1.33543*10^7 r] - 
 BesselJ[11, 1.33543*10^7 r]) ((0.13491 + 5.55112*10^-17 I) E^(
  2.00315 + 1.33543*10^7 z)
   HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) - 
    z] + ((0.5 + 
       0.929666 I) E^((-2.00315 - 
        1.07735 I) - (0. + 7.18231*10^6 I) z) + (0.0674552 + 
       0.125422 I) E^((0. - 
        1.07735 I) + (0. + 7.18231*10^6 I) z)) (1 - 
    HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) - z]) (1 - 
    HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) + z]) + 
 E^(-1.33543*10^7 z) HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) + 
z])],Re[(4.78788*10^-8 - 3.6838*10^-24 I) BesselJ[10, 
1.33543*10^7 r] (20000000 E^(-1.33543*10^7 z)
   DiracDelta[-3 + 20000000 z] - (2.69821*10^6 + 
    1.11022*10^-9 I) E^(2.00315 + 1.33543*10^7 z)
   DiracDelta[3 + 20000000 z] - 
 20000000 ((0.5 + 
       0.929666 I) E^((-2.00315 - 
        1.07735 I) - (0. + 7.18231*10^6 I) z) + (0.0674552 + 
       0.125422 I) E^((0. - 
        1.07735 I) + (0. + 7.18231*10^6 I) z)) DiracDelta[-3 + 
    20000000 z] (1 - 
    HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) - z]) + (1.80163*10^6 + 
    7.41313*10^-10 I) E^(2.00315 + 1.33543*10^7 z)
   HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) - z] + 
 20000000 ((0.5 + 
       0.929666 I) E^((-2.00315 - 
        1.07735 I) - (0. + 7.18231*10^6 I) z) + (0.0674552 + 
       0.125422 I) E^((0. - 
        1.07735 I) + (0. + 7.18231*10^6 I) z)) DiracDelta[
   3 + 20000000 z] (1 - 
    HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) + 
      z]) + ((6.67715*10^6 - 
       3.59116*10^6 I) E^((-2.00315 - 
        1.07735 I) - (0. + 7.18231*10^6 I) z) - (900816. - 
       484484. I) E^((0. - 
        1.07735 I) + (0. + 7.18231*10^6 I) z)) (1 - 
    HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) - z]) (1 - 
    HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) + z]) - 
 1.33543*10^7 E^(-1.33543*10^7 z)
   HeavisideTheta[-(3/20000000) + z])]}
```

Thanks!
Best,
Denis

Comment: It's because of `hfieldzr`...I think.

Comment: Just want to emphasize this is not a pathology of my field, as when I use VectorDensityPlot I do not obtain this weirdness.

Comment: So you said. I just want to emphasize that it has to do with your vector field. I can't say how, perhaps no one can, without knowing its definition.

Comment: @denis I think Michael is trying to tell you that, unless you show us the details of your field, there is very little else we can suggest.

Comment: Dear All. Thanks.
I've just included the field within my post.

Comment: @denis you say "this strange vector fields". What about it is strange? What needs fixing in your option?

Comment: Also how does your field depend on `r` and `z`? These are the plot variables but they don't seem to show up in the "field" you provided

Comment: Also `Re` will automatically thread over lists so you should be able to just plot `Re[hfieldzr[m, ko, ki, r, 0, z]]` directly without having to use `[[1]]` or `[[2]]`

Comment: Dear @b3m2a1, I'm sorry. Now the vector field is complete!
I've just included the same plot but now using VectorDensityPlot function.

Thanks!